# Adding error bars to a graph with file data using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a file named J.txt that has data in 3 columns, the third being the value for the error bar (symmetrical) like this:

```
2454501.81752 0.0018087812 9.69699358080375E-005
2454537.77104 0.0030887732 0.0001610068
2454603.70872 0.0022500182 0.0001230047
2454640.56455 0.0013261298 7.57575739971879E-005
2454662.63581 0.0017888998 9.91743434734387E-005
```

and I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plotfile('J.txt', delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1),  
             names=('V', 'V-B'), marker='o', markersize=2, markeredgewidth=0.1, markeredgecolor='black', 
             color= 'green', label= "Cluster", linestyle='None', newfig=False)

plt.show()
```

I'm stuck trying to add the error bars to the plot because I don't know how to relate the columns in the file to `plt.errorbar` (if that's what I should be using).

Cheers.

Comment: This may not help if you want to use `plt.plotfile()`, but you could first load the data using numpy with `np.loadtxt()` and then just use [`plt.errorbar()`](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_demo.html), supplying the third column to the `yerryerr` (or `xerr`) keyword.

Comment: I agree with Will Barnes. Separate the loading of the data and the plotting. This way you can also test in between the two operations what your data actually look like after being read in.

Comment: how do you put the horizontal bars to the upper and lower limit of the error bars?

Comment: @CharlieParker adding a value to the kwarg `capsize` in the function `plt.plotfile()` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Will and roadrunner66's suggestions I digged for a solution like that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

col0 = np.genfromtxt('J.txt', usecols=(0), delimiter=' ', dtype=None)
col1 = np.genfromtxt('J.txt', usecols=(1), delimiter=' ', dtype=None)
col2 = np.genfromtxt('J.txt', usecols=(2), delimiter=' ', dtype=None)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.plot(col0, col1, c='b', marker='o', markeredgewidth=0, linewidth=0, markersize=3)
ax1.errorbar(col0, col1, yerr=col2, linestyle=' ', c= 'b')
plt.show()
```

Numpy's `np.genfromtxt` brings the data like I needed it to and matplotlib's `ax1.errorbar` lets me put the error bars using the `yerr` value for the Y axis.

Comment: how do you put the horizontal bars to the upper and lower limit of the error bars?

Comment: You need to set a value for the `capsize` parameter in `errorbar`, otherwise it will default to 0 and the horizontal bars will not be shown.

For my case I would have: 
ax1.errorbar(col0, col1, yerr=col2, linestyle=' ', c= 'b', **capsize=1**)